# JQM: how to de-couple select displayed text from the text of the first option

Tags: jquery, select, mobile, jquery-mobile

I need to "de-couple" the text displayed on a closed select box from the text of the first option (or the "selected" one).
The reason for this is I want to use the closed select as a label, and the first (or selected) option to select all the items.

To make things clearer (at least I hope so :-), I give an example of the html:

```
<select id="fruits">
    <option selected="selected">Fruits</option>
    <option>cherry</option>
    <option>apple</option>
</select>
```

Which would give a selected item text of "Fruits", but I want to show - say - "Select all fruits".

I'm experimenting with something like:

```
$("#fruits").bind('click', function() {
    $("#fruits option:first-child").html("Select all fruits");
});
```

but it seems to work on desktop's browsers, but not on mobile's (at least not on Android 2.3.4 browser).

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally solve this problem, just better reading [QDM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html#&ui-state=dialog): Using a select whith these attributes:

```
 multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false"
```

(multiple selection is a requirement, for me; sorry this answer does not fully covers single selects...), JQM builds a popup, with the first option (which must not have a "value" set) as the title. So you can use the first option (without any "value"), as the label for your (closed) select.

This is the relevant code from the JQM docs page:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-9" class="select">Choose shipping method(s):</label>
    <select name="select-choice-9" id="select-choice-9" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Choose options</option>
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```